# Best non-native IPv6 connectivity (in Europe)

Tags: ipv6, tunneling

What is the best (most stable, fastest, easy to setup) way to get IPv6 connectivity and addressspace in Europe? And, why?

I'm running a small hosting outfit from a rented server in Germany and would like to start providing IPv6 capabilities.

I've seen that [SixXS](http://www.sixxs.net/) has a big showing in Germany, but I'd like hear a broader set of opinions before committing to a tunnel broker.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Hurricane Electric](http://www.he.net/) has POPs all over Europe, and distributes free IPv6 tunnels. I have one in France (`www.bortzmeyer.org`) and I'm quite happy with their reliability.

Comment: Same here. I used to have reliability issues with a different tunnel broker but Hurricane have been fairly reliable. They do have some downtime from time to time but it's rare and short.

Answer (score 1):

regarding sixxs, read [this](https://rejo.zenger.nl/misc/1221048210.php)

personally I use tunnelbroker.net - physically it's in the states, but as long as you don't have native ipv6 bandwidth will be as much as your tunnel provider has allocated

Comment: Rejo lost me down here: "Downtime is not a problem at all, but the idiot style of communicating is - which of course is your right to do so." I'm also wondering why he didn't go along with the SLA offer and specified "communicate estimate of downtime within 24 hours of incident" or "less then 3 days of consecutive downtime."

Comment: the bottom line is they can interrupt the service whenever they want, for whatever reason; try tunnelbroker for a while and see if it fits ok for your needs

Comment: Jeroen does get a bit snippy at times on the forum, but does a good job of providing a pretty good service (they do drop from time to time, so not perfect service).  Probably just overworked like the rest of us.  :-)  I use both SixXS and Hurricane Electric, depending on the site.

Comment: The link in the answer is no longer working.

Answer (score 0):

I've been very pleased with [sixxs](http://www.sixxs.net/), who've provided me with a reliable subnet years. I'm using a static tunnel that's initiated by my Ubuntu Linux server. It runs radvd to advertise the subnet to hosts on the LAN.